# How to print values of a object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
       firstName: "A",
       lastName: "C",
       number: "999",
    },
};
```

How can I print the values of the object `friends` using a `for...loop`?

Comment: `friends.bill.firstName` etc?

Comment: yes Andy, I want to print the values

Comment: how do you want the values printed? [what code have you written to try to solve your own issue](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @hridaynehu, you need to be more specific in your question as to what you want to do. Do you want to loop over the objects in `friends`? Do you want to print their properties/values to the console or add them to a DOM element?

Comment: Yes, I want to use for..in loop to print the properties.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You know what a `for...loop` is and in my first comment I showed you how to access the values. What else do you need?

Answer (score 3):

```
var friends = {
    bill:
    {
        firstName: "A",
        lastName: "C",        
        number: "999",
    },
    print: function () {
        for (var p in this.bill)
            console.log(p + ' ' + this.bill[p]);
    }
};
```

This code will print, is that what you need?

```
friends.print();
```

Comment: The OP needs a `for...loop`.

Comment: posted before the exact need was defined :) already edited

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make a suggestion that might make your coding a little easier. Instead of using an object to contain a list of friends, use an array instead. An array is a list after all, and Javascript comes with some really useful array functions that can help you in the long run.

```
var friends = [
  {
   name: 'Bill Z',
   firstName: "Bill",
   lastName: "X",
   number: "999",
  },
  {
   name: 'Sam Y',
   firstName: "Sam",
   lastName: "Y",
   number: "999",
  }    
];
```

To get the list of friends you might use a couple of loops; one to loop over the list of objects, and one to loop over the properties of each object:

```
function listFriends() {
  for (var i = 0, l = friends.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (var p in friends[i]) {
        console.log(p + ': ' + friends[i][p]);
    }
  }
}
```

Or to get HTML out:

```
function listFriends() {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0, l = friends.length; i < l; i++) {
    html += '<b>' + friends[i].firstName + '</b><br/>';
    for (var p in friends[i]) {
        html += p.toUpperCase() + ': ' + friends[i][p] + '<br/>';
    }
  }
  return html;
}
```

You might also like to access the list of friends to find one in particular. In this example I use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
function getFriend(prop, value) {
  return friends.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj[prop] === value;
  });
}

console.log(getFriend('firstName', 'Sam')) // { name="Sam Y", firstName="Sam", lastName="Y"}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yx6L/).

Hopefully you'll find some of this useful.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to print only the members of within `friends.bill`, you might want to use a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, for example:

```
for(var p in friends.bill) 
    console.log(p + ": " + friends.bill[p])
```

Which will print this in the console:

```
firstName: A VM579:3
lastName: C VM579:3
number: 999
```

Comment: Yes. I wanted to use for..in loop.

Comment: @CaptainJohn Removed. Original question was more vague.